# C# - Updating pictureBox.Image during Runtime causes Error

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

i am trying to change the pictureBox.Image during Runtime. I have several Model classes with a picture stored, whenever i click on a MenuStripItem i call the method "ChangePictureBoxImages". Till then there is no error (the pB is invisible!) but once i call the method to make the pB visible i get an Error. The Error code: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll".

Research said i should dispose the picturebox and set it to "null", however this does NOT help.

My Code:

```
using (Image current = BitmapManipulator.EvaluateMesurement(CSV_Name1, max_Rows, max_Col, var.TopImage, var.BitmapToManipulate, pB_ColourScale_Evaluation.Image, var.BitmapToManipulate, var.Filepath, var.FoldID))
                {

                    var.LastEvaluationImage = current;
                    BitmapManipulator.CombineImagesAndSaveThem_Evaluation(var.TopImage, var.BitmapToManipulate, pB_ColourScale_Evaluation.Image, var.Filepath, var.FoldID);  //saves the Files as jpg 
                    if (var.CurrentlyShownToUser) //checks if the MenuStripItem is the active one
                    {
                        if (var.LastEvaluationImage == null) { MessageBox.Show("the image is null");} //only for debugging purpose -> does never call
                        ChangePictureBoxImages(); 

                    }
                }
```

and the ChangePictureBoxImages():

```
      public void ChangePictureBoxImages()
    {

        foreach (Fold fold in FoldExisting)    
        {
            if (fold.FoldID == LastSelectedMenuStripItem_Name)       //the clicked item is the last Selected MenuStripItem
            {
                if (fold.LastEvaluationImage != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(pB_Evaluation_Bottom.Image.ToString() + "   " + fold.LastEvaluationImage.ToString());
                    pB_Evaluation_Bottom.Image = fold.LastEvaluationImage;
                }


                pB_Evaluation_Top.Image = fold.TopImage;
            }

        }
    }
```

There is no error till then, the error appears once i call   "pB_Evaluation_Bottom.visible = true". (or if i called the visible method first first the error appears upon changing the Image!) The error also appears upon clicking 2 times on the MenuStripItem. I load the picture from the Class Fold as following:

This will set an image in the fold class, this image will then be manipulated and stored in  LastEvaluationImage

```
        private void setTheImages(string PictureToManipulate, string PathToTopImage)
    {
        try
        {
            this.BitmapToManipulate_intern = (Image)Image.FromFile(@PictureToManipulate, true);
            this.TopImage_intern = (Image)Image.FromFile(@PathToTopImage, true);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The BitMap for the manipulation process and the top image is not created.");
        }

    }
```

and the LastEvaluationImage where the last picture is stored -> this will be called to be the new pb.Image

```
        private Image LastEvaluationImage_intern;
    public Image LastEvaluationImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LastEvaluationImage_intern;
        }
        set
        {
            if (LastEvaluationImage_intern != null) { LastEvaluationImage_intern.Dispose(); LastEvaluationImage_intern = null; }
            this.LastEvaluationImage_intern = value;
            this.LastEvaluationTime_intern = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

I know this is a little complex, but i hope someone can help me.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

***UPDATE: The Error must be in the following Code:*** 
The BitmapManipulator.EvaluateMeasurement  Code :

```
 public Image EvaluateMesurement(double[][] MeasuredValues, int max_Rows, int max_Col, Image pB_Evaluation_Top, Image pB_Evaluation_Bottom, Image pB_EvaluationColourScale, Image ManipulatedBitmap, string PathMeasurementFiles, string Foldname) 
    {

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ManipulatedBitmap))  
        {
            // the data array sizes:
            int number_nio = 0;
            int number_total = 0;
            List<FileInfo> LastFiles;   
            int got_number_for_trends = Properties.Settings.Default.TrendNumber;



            SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(red);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                Random rnd = new Random(8);
                int[,] data = new int[max_Col, max_Rows];



                // scale the tile size:
                float sx = 1f * bitmap.Width / data.GetLength(0);
                float sy = 1f * bitmap.Height / data.GetLength(1);

                LastFiles = FM.GetLastFiles_Trend(ref got_number_for_trends, PathMeasurementFiles);  
                double[][] CSV_Statistiken = FM.LastFilesToCSV(got_number_for_trends, true, LastFiles, PathMeasurementFiles);    


                for (int x = 0; x < max_Col; x++)     
                {
                    for (int y = max_Rows - 1; y >= 0; y--)  
                    {
                        number_total++;
                        RectangleF r = new RectangleF(x * sx, y * sy, sx, sy);

                        if (MeasuredValues[y][x] < Properties.Settings.Default.Threshhold) 
                        {
                            number_nio++;
                            if (CSV_Statistiken[y][x] == Properties.Settings.Default.TrendNumber)  
                            {
                                myBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(150, black);
                                g.FillRectangle(myBrush, r);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                myBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(150, red);
                                g.FillRectangle(myBrush, r);
                            }

                        }
                        else    
                        {

                            myBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(150, green);
                            g.FillRectangle(myBrush, r);
                        }

                    }


                }
            }

            return bitmap;  
        }
    }
```

This returned bitmap will be stored in fold.LastEvaluationImage as following:

```
using (Image current = BitmapManipulator.EvaluateMesurement(CSV_Name1, max_Rows, max_Col, var.TopImage, var.BitmapToManipulate, pB_ColourScale_Evaluation.Image, var.BitmapToManipulate, var.Filepath, var.FoldID))
            {

                var.LastEvaluationImage = current;
            }
```

Comment: Whats the type of `fold.LastEvaluationImage`?

Comment: its an Image (jpeg)

Comment: It's of the .Net data type `Image`? Do you load it from a file or a resource?

Comment: I load it in the "LastEvaluationImage" the code is in the Question, last part, it gets modified in the 1. Code i postet, is then saved in "current" and then stored witht he last code in  fold.LastEvaluationImage.( with set this.LastEvaluationImage_intern = value;) Is this what you meant? or you wanted something else? thanks for your time

Comment: Did you try to set the jpeg file as a source for a `PictureBox` directly? Just for debbuging purposes. Perhaps there is a problem with the file

Comment: Yeah i tried it, the clicking on MenuStripItem then works, so i could delimit the error! It only occours when the "LastEvaluationImage" is changed! I will update the Question with the Code of how i manipulate the image and then store it in "LastEvaluationImage" there must be a mistake!

Comment: Call Dispose() only on bitmap objects that you no longer need.  So the *previous* one, not the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a disposed bitmap. It shouldn't be surprising you can't draw something that no longer exists :)

The `using (bitmap)` is the last thing you want in this case. The `bitmap` *must* survive longer than the scope of the using. And the `using (current)` in the caller has the same problem - you're again disposing the image way too early. You can only dispose it when it's clear that it isn't going to be used ever again - e.g. when you replace it with a new image.

To elaborate, `using` does nothing but call `Dispose` when you leave its scope. In the case of `Bitmap` (which is just a "thin" wrapper around a GDI bitmap), this releases the memory where the actual image data is stored. There isn't anything interesting left, so there's nothing to draw (and you'd basically be calling `DrawBitmap(NULL)` as far as GDI is concerned).

Comment: Hmm i understand what you mean, but when i use:
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(ManipulatedBitmap)
{ 
  ..... some functions
  return b;
}

shouldnt the bitmap b first be returned and Afterwards disposed? or will the returned bitmap be disposed afterwards too? Basically does dispose delete all references like "return b" too? or just the bitmap itself?

Comment: @christian890 "Being disposed" is not a property of the reference, it's a property of the object. You're not *copying* the bitmap when you return it - you just return a reference to the original bitmap. You're destroying the one object - it doesn't matter how many references to the destroyed object exist, it's still destroyed.

Comment: Ah damnit! that could be really it then! Ill check it and answer with the result! THANKS this really does help, been looking for this for days! stupid me!

Comment: @christian890 Note that in .NET, "disposed" and "destroyed" are really orthogonal - you never really "destroy" any object, the GC does. By design, `Dispose` is used to release *unmanaged* (non-.NET) resources, which aren't tracked by the garbage collector. There's no way to destroy a .NET object deterministically from your code. If you're coming from a background like C++, these things can be quite confusing since they *seem* similar to some C++ concepts, but rarely are. Make sure to look at things with fresh eyes, especially in memory management - .NET is *very* different.

Comment: This totally solved my Problems! Thank you so much! I will gladly take your advice! I think exactly that was my problem, i really am new to - .Net and came from C++ =) Have a nice day! THANKS